# UI tab rotate steal focus

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, rotation

I'm using jquery ui tab and using rotate in slideshow.

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav" id="slide-controls">
        <li class="ui-tabs-selected" id="slide-control-slide_1"><a class="selected" href="#slide_1">Slide 1</a></li>
        <li id="slide-control-slide_2"><a href="#slide_2">Slide 2</a></li>
        <li id="slide-control-slide_3"><a href="#slide_3">Slide 3</a></li>
        <li id="slide-control-slide_4"><a href="#slide_4">Slide 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Q1)**
My slideshow is at the top, while my page is pretty long.  So everytime when I scroll down to the bottom of my page, and when the slideshow change slide (auto rotate), the focus will land on the anchor tag above. So looks like the jquery ui tab rotate steal my focus.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Q2)**
Another question - how can I stop an element from focusing?  (somehow related to my previous quesion )

Thanks

Comment: wheres your jquery code. Also can you reproduce this by creating an empty html page with a bunch of dummy text.

Comment: Here is a sample with what you want: http://jsbin.com/aqufu4/edit. About the long page, or you set a fixed height to your tabs container, our you do what I did: scroll down on every tab change. About the focus, it was easy. See there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height on your slideshow. Here's a solution to your answer [JQuery UI Tabs Causing Screen to "Jump"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243794/jquery-ui-tabs-causing-screen-to-jump)

Answer (score 0):

Your second question should be easy.

`object.onfocus = function() {return false;}`