# how to create a link to a specific tab? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
            });
        });
        $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
    }
});
```

```
<ul id="verticalNav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Section I</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section II</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section III</a></li>
</ul>


    <div id="sections">
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <p>Some content specific to this section...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <img src="#" alt="BADGER" />
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section3">
            <img src="#g" alt="SNAKE" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have to create specific link for each tab example index.html#section1 , index.html#section2

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work? How it should work?

Comment: In the page you provided everything works fine. When you click the link to the section it follows it, that is hides all the sections and shows the one specified in link. Then, the default links behaviour navigates to the top of the section. Do you want it to __not__ navigate but just show the section?

Comment: Hi matewka, how I can show the default section.

Comment: what is the default section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(window.location.hash)
{
    showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
}
```

**Full Code**

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() { // no need for each loop
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { // Use $('ul#verticalNav li a').click
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
        //});
        if(window.location.hash) // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        {
           showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @user2913707 I didn't find `showSection function` in your page. Check my `answer` once again.

Comment: Hi Rohan Kumar, Now working fine, thanks you so much

Comment: Page is vertically scrolling when click on the tab, how to fix. thanks

Comment: How to fix the page scroll to top when clicking different tabs in jquery vertical tab, demo link: http://www.bajistech.info/tiltindicators.html#TiltWatch-Plus1

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times, should be easy to find with some googling.

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {                   
            window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
        }
    });
```

Answered here [jQuery UI tabs, update url when clicking on a different tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777518/jquery-ui-tabs-update-url-when-clicking-on-a-different-tab)

Answer (score 0):

You could put each section inside an anchor tag with that specific name. For example, for section1 you would do so:

```
<a name="section1">
    <div class='section" id="section1">
        <p> Some content specific to this section...</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Then, you could simply reference that section like this (from the same page):

```
<a href="#section1">Click me to get to section1!</a>
```

If you were to try and reference `section1` (which would be let's say on `index.html`) from another page like `about.html`, you would simply have the following anchor element:

```
<a href="index.html#section1">Clicke me to navigate from about.html to section1 on index.html<a>
```

Also, you could try using `window.location.hash` [it is supported in all major browsers] as follows:

```
window.location.hash = 'section1';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
code with demo

page will scroll to specific section on clicking the section title

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/